# Actionscript: get textfields and assign them dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a highscore list.
I have a movieclip ("highscore") and in it i have dynamic textfields with instance names. Now i'm trying to get those textfields so that i can change the text inside. Since i'm getting them in a loop i get them with getChildByName (and this works). But what i get back is a displayObject and therefore i get the **error**: `implicit coercion of a value of type class to an unrelated type...`

I know what the error is.. but i have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
private function updateSingleList(result:XML):void
        {
            if(result['header']['success'] != 'true'){
                return;
            }

            for(var i:uint = 0; i < result['items']['item'].length(); i++)
            {
                var pos:uint            = i+1;
                var name:String         = 'name_' + pos;
                var score:String        = 'score_' + pos;
                var rowName:TextField   = highscore.getChildByName(name);
                var rowScore:TextField  = highscore.getChildByName(score);
                    rowName.text        = result['items']['item'][i]['name'].toString();
                    rowScore.text       = result['items']['item'][i]['score'].toString();
            }
        }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify that the child you want is a TextField :

```
var rowName:TextField   = highscore.getChildByName('name_' + pos) as TextField;
rowName.text = result['items']['item'][i]['name'].toString();
```